# Cumulative sum with breaks

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I have for example the following table:

[image]

> **Datasource** = stock moviment of some retail stores
>
> **STORE_N** = Number of the store
>
> **MOD** = type of stock change. FC = sales (negative sign), AJ = stock adjust, DI = stock position
>
> **QTY** = stock change quantity
>
> **TMOV** = sign of the stock change
>
> **PRODUCT_CODE** = code of the store product

I would like to obtain a cumulative sum column with multiple group parameters and with a condition to only start the cumulative some after the first line in the column "STOCK" with value <> 0.

Desired result:

[image]

dbn = database
CE19 AND CE01 are table inside this database
My code:

```
SELECT 
dbn.CE19.STORE_N,
dbn.CE19.MOD,
dbn.CE19.DATE,
DATE(dbn.CE19.DATE) AS DATE_2,
dbn.CE19.QTY,
dbn.CE19.STOQUE,
dbn.CE19.TMOV, 
dbn.CE01.PRODUCT_CODE, 
IF(dbn.CE19.MOD = 'AJ', dbn.CE19.QTY, sum(IF(dbn.CE19.MOD in ('FC', 'DI', 'NF', 'AJ'), 
    IF(dbn.CE19.TMOV = '-', dbn.CE19.QTY*(-1), dbn.CE19.QTY), 0)) 
    over (partition by dbn.ce19.STORE_N, dbn.ce01.PRODUCT_CODE order by dbn.ce19.STORE_N, dbn.ce19.data, dbn.ce01.PRODUCT_CODE)) as CUMULATIVE_SUM
FROM dbn.CE19 
LEFT JOIN dbn.CE01 ON dbn.CE19.ID_PRODUCT = dbn.CE01.ID_PRODUCT 
WHERE DATE(dbn.CE19.DATE) BETWEEN '2021-10-12' AND '2021-12-05'
ORDER BY dbn.CE01.PRODUCT_CODE, dbn.CE19.DATE
```

The Result:

[image]

The cumulative sum with multiple criteria/grouping (partition) is working but I don't know how to put a condition to only start the cumulative sum just after the first "stock" value different than zero for every partition configuration.

SQLFIDDLE:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc435/2

Comment: Please do NOT post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, I'll edit with consumable text